# for loop not working as excpected

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

I have a class, with a variable like this:

```
@tags = { 'tag-test': [ 'ZnVuY3Rpb24gcmFuZG9tKCkgeyBbbmF0aXZlIGNvZGVdIH0xNDcwODI4MzQ4Mzk3TmFO' ] }
```

Now I'm trying to go over all indexes, then remove one of their values IF they have it :

```
rmtag = (t) ->
    i = @tags[t].indexOf socket.uid
    console.log "Checking tag " + t + " index is " + i
    if i != -1
        console.log "Removing " + i
        @tags[t].splice i, 1

rmtag = rmtag.bind @

for d, i in @tags
    rmtag i
```

In this case, `socket.uid` has the value of `ZnVuY3Rpb24gcmFuZG9tKCkgeyBbbmF0aXZlIGNvZGVdIH0xNDcwODI4MzQ4Mzk3TmFO`.

Any ideas on why this isn't working ?

Comment: Maybe best way is use filter e.g. `tags[i].filter((tag) => tag != socket.uid )`?

Comment: For some reason, the for loop doesn't even get executed once. If I `console.log @tags` before the for loop, it has an entry.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for some reason the for loop didn't get executed. Anyway, by first listing the keys and then going over them works as expected:

```
tags = @tags

# Remove entry from all tags
rmtag = (t) ->
    @tags[t] = @tags[t].filter((tag) => tag != socket.uid)

rmtag = rmtag.bind @
keys = Object.keys tags
for k in keys
    rmtag k
```

Answer (score 0):

`for ... in` is used to loop over arrays but `@tags` is an object. You use `for ... of` to loop over objects:

```
for k, v of @tags
    rmtag k
```

If you say `for d, i in tags`, CoffeeScript will produce JavaScript like this:

```
for (i = j = 0, len = tags.length; j < len; i = ++j) {
    d = tags[i];
    ...
}
```

But you don't have a `length` property in `@tags` so the `j < len` condition fails immediately and the loop never executes.